# Is there a way to prevent Android app code shrinker R8 from changing line numbers?

Tags: android, android-r8

Android Studio started to use [R8](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code) instead of ProGuard by default recently.

The stack traces from ProGuard are fairly easy to understand without using any tools despite code is obfuscated. Let's use the following example:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Boolean.booleanValue()' on a null object reference
    at net.foo.anroid.Foo.wb.d(SourceFile:453)
    at net.foo.anroid.Foo.wb.a(SourceFile:213)
    at net.foo.anroid.Foo.wb.n(SourceFile:103)
    at net.foo.anroid.Foo.qa.run(Unknown Source:2)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Usually I know exactly to which file net.foo.anroid.Foo.wb corresponds, and the line numbers (e.g. 453, 213...) are the actual lines numbers in the source file for ProGuard.

However, for R8, the only way to figure out which line is which is looking them up in mapping.txt.

This is really a significant nuisance. If there is no good way to locate the source code quickly from a stack trace, I will go back to ProGuard for this reason alone.

Is there a way to prevent R8 from changing line numbers?

Comment: No. But you can probably deobfuscate it. ProGuard at least offered reverse filters for that.

Comment: @Zoe  Thank you for the clarification. Could turn your comment to an answer for me to accept?  Yes, I can deobfuscate it with mapping.txt, but it is a pain.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This has been discussed from time to time on the R8 team, and we went with always optimizing line numbers for a number of reasons:

- It saved in the area of 5% on the dex size
- For release builds where optimizations like inlining are turned on retracing is needed anyway to expand the inlined frames
- It is one less option in the testing matrix

Right now it is always turned off for debug builds, and for release builds when both -dontoptimize (implies no inlining) and -dontobfuscate are set in the configuration.

When you use retrace (remember to use the one from Proguard version 6 or later) you don't need to cut out the stacktrace, as retrace will pass non stack trace lines through unmodified.

There is currently no library to do this in the app, and as that requires the mapping file to be included in the app that defeats the purpose of making apks small.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the elucidation.  I have to admit that I feel I understand perhaps 80% of your explanation.  I am unable to restore the original line numbers with Retrace.  I am using ProGuard under "C:\Users\myid\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\proguard\lib" dated 2019-03-31.  The class and method names are restored correctly with ReTrace.  The lines numbers remain the same.

Comment: The problem is that unfortunately the version of ProGuard in the Android Sdk is an old version 4.7, so you need to go download the latest version from https://sourceforge.net/projects/proguard/files/proguard/6.0/, where retrace should work correctly with line numbers.

Comment: Thank you.  I downloaded it and used proguardgui.bat.  it works like a charm.  I did not notice the download button when directed from R8's official page.

Answer (score 1):

Set these in the ProGuard configuration:

```
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
```

then use [ReTrace jar](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/retrace):

> ReTrace can read an obfuscated stack trace and restore it to what it would look like without obfuscation. The restoration is based on the mapping file that ProGuard can write out during obfuscation. The mapping file links the original class names and class member names to their obfuscated names.

```
java -jar retrace.jar [options...] mapping_file [stacktrace_file]
```

for example:

```
java -jar retrace.jar mapping.txt stacktrace.log
```

Comment: Thank you for lending a hand here.  I am trying to avoid using ReTrace.  I am dealing with stack traces in debugging logs reported by app users.  The logs have all kinds of information.  It would be too much a hassle to extract a trace and put it in a file, then use ReTrace.  I just want to look at the trace, then open the source code file, and use the line numbers to find the trouble spots.

Comment: @Hong eg. with Crashlytics, the `mapping.txt` is automatically being uploaded.

Comment: As I explained, I am not talking about crash analysis which works great with the uploaded mapping.txt.   I am talking about stack traces generated by the app in debugging log files sent by app users.  I assume there is no way that an app can deobfuscate a stack trace in the code.

Comment: @Hong while keeping the file-names & line numbers it' still possible to decode them with retrace - which is anytime better then manually looking up the names and numbers. one just has to keep them `mapping.txt` for each version.

Comment: Sorry for my rudimentary question.  I ran java -jar retrace.jar mapping.txt, then paste a stack trace to the input, but could not figure out how to end the input.  Ctr+Z does not work.  Could you offer a tip?

Comment: @Hong you can add a stack-trace file as further argument; so it can be automated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192993/discussion-between-hong-and-martin-zeitler).